# Combining Radgrid, RadajaxPanel, ValidationSummary and a custom "turn field in error to red" issue

Tags: ajax, telerik, radgrid, validationsummary

Here's the format of a sample page :

```
*Validation Summary*

Label : [input]

Label : [input]

###############
# RadGrid     #
###############

###############
# RadGrid     #
###############

Label : [input]

[save button]
```

1st version :

- When I push the save button, the whole page reloads. The validation summary is filled with errors (or not) and the input that are in error are shown in red.
- When I open a RadGrid (custom edit template), the whole page reloads and the save button is desactivated.
- **Problem** : The whole page is reloaded when we open a grid and it's uhh... not what the customer wants...?

2nd version :

- We have put radAjaxPanel around the radgrids, so when you open a grid, only the grid reloads. **Problem** : The save button is not desactivated anymore.
- If I click the save button, the whole page still reloads.

3rd version :

- We added a radAjaxPanel to the save button and *a line* (see footnote) to reload this radAjaxPanel when a RadGrid is opened or closed
- Now the button is activated/desactivated properly.
- **Problem** : When I push the save button, only the button reloads and if there are error on some fields, they are not turned to red. The validation summary still work.

4th version :

- Added *a line* (foot note) to reload the whole page when the save button is pushed.
- now the field in error are turned to red
- **Problem** : this extra postback make the validation summary dissapear.

So, any ideas on how could I have all these *options* working together?
The easy way out would be to convince the customer to abandon radAjaxPanel (because *I feel we use them incorrectly* anyway and it brings little advantages).

The whole project architecture is somewhat complex (we *emulate* .net mvc with webforms (!)) and I feel like code would just add cluttering to the questions, but if you think some specific parts would need more details/code, feel free to ask.

<sub><sup>MainRadAjaxPanel.ResponseScripts.Add(string.Format("$find('{0}').ajaxRequest();", MainRadAjaxPanel.ClientID));</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `RadAjaxManager` control instead of several `RadAjaxPanels`.  The `RadAjaxManager` allows more flexibility around what item(s) are triggered by what control(s).  Unfortunately I can't give specific example with the information above but hopefully this will get you pointed in the right direction.  You can definitely do what you're wanting with the `RadAjaxManager` and get everything working.  Just be mindful of AJAX triggers and updates, i.e., what control triggers an AJAX update (e.g. your save button) and what receives the corresponding update (your ValidationSummary).

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-ajaxmanager.html